# What is the best way to combine various object and print them out accordingly?

Tags: python, class, for-loop, append

So I am attempting to write a program in Python that builds a list of students and eventually prints them out to the screen. For each student the user chooses to add, the input of first name, last name, and ID number are taken.

My issue is that although I am attempting to append each new person created onto a list called studentList[], when I print the list out at the end, I get an output of the correct number of student but all containing the same information as the last student I entered.

For example, if I add the students 'Johnny Tsunami 4', 'Billy Bobblie 23', 'Biggus Dickus 77', my output will read:

```
Biggus Dickus 77
Biggus Dickus 77
Biggus Dickus 77
```

I am not sure where my error is, be it in the list appending mechanism or in my for loop used to print out the   objects. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
class Student(object):
    fname = ""
    lname= ""
    idNo = 0

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, idnumber):
        self.fname = firstname
        self.lname = lastname
        self.idNo = idnumber


def make_student(fname, lname, idNo):
  student = Student(fname, lname, idNo)
  return student


def main():
    maxStudCount = 0
    studentList = []
    studQuery = raw_input("Would you like to add a student? (Type 'Yes'     or 'No'): ")

    while studQuery == 'Yes' and maxStudCount < 10:
        fname = raw_input("Enter first name: ")
        lname = raw_input("Enter last name: ")
        idNo = raw_input("Enter ID No: ")

        person = make_student(fname, lname, idNo)
        studentList.append(person)

        maxStudCount = maxStudCount + 1
        studQuery = raw_input("Add another student? ('Yes' or 'No'): ")


    for item in studentList:
        print fname, lname, idNo


if __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing the local variables fname, lname, and idNo that you last set in the while loop. The variables that you want are stored separately in each instance of the Student class. Try this for loop instead:

```
for item in studentList:
     print item.fname, item.lname, item.idNo
```

Comment: Thank you kamses. Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help.